# jQuery Promo code function

Tags: jquery, jquery-calculation

I'm using the following code to execute a value update based on a code entered. But it returns wrong.

Ex: If the promo code is to reduce the price by 10, and the current total is 100, this returns 80. which should be 90.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#promo-code').keyup(function() {
  if ($("input:text[name='promo-code']").val() == "intro") {
    var promoval = parseFloat($("input:text[name='total']").val());
    $("#total").val(promoval-10);  
  }
});
```

Comment: can you pls show some html?

Comment: instead of keyup, use change to check the final promo code value only

Comment: [How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)

Comment: Your code works just fine Jude, But we can't help you identify the problem without your html code

Comment: Hi, this is the code and issue exactly. https://jsfiddle.net/JudeAinsly/gxa0rjkj/ (answer should be 90, but the math runs 2 times)

Answer (score 0):

Try some else instead of `keyup` like `focusout` as below. Because when you are using `keyup` it gets fire every keyup event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#promo-code').focusout(function() {
    if ($("input:text[name='promo-code']").val() == "intro") {
      var promoval = parseFloat($("input:text[name='total']").val());
      $("#total").val(promoval-10);  
    }
  });
});
```

Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$('#total').val(100);
$('#promo-code').focusout(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "intro") {
    var promoval = parseFloat($('#total').val());
    $("#total").val(promoval - 10);
  } else {
    alert('invalid promo');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="promo-code">
<input type="text" id="total">
```

Comment: Thank you RaJesh. But the reason I was using `keyup` is to update the total field without a click. Also, even though I use this method, if I re-enter the same code and focusout, the total keeps reducing each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

An improvised solution for your problem:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('#promo-code').change(function() {

        if ($(this).val() == "intro") {

           var promoval = parseFloat($("input:text[name='total']").val());
           $("#total").val(promoval-10);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How can you improvise something, that you don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

I hope you set the html correctly, and the keyup functionality should work just fine. But you would also like to check other methods as mentioned in other answers here. I would suggest that you go for `change` method.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#promo-code').keyup(function() {
  if ($("input:text[name='promo-code']").val() == "intro") {
    var promoval = parseFloat($("input:text[name='total']").val());
    $("#total").val(promoval-10);  
  }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="promo-code" type="text" id="promo-code"/>
<input name="total" type="text" value="100" id="total"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, yes the HTML is correct. 'change' does the job. But I was trying to update the price real time. :/ any other suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by trying to update the price in real time? From the code you have provided, it is not clear which is the price in real time. Please make your question a bit more clear